# calculate the mean with unequal weights

Tags: r, simulation, weighted-sampling

I am doing a simulation with longitudinal curves. These curves are generated from $y=2x$ and $y=\cos(2\pi x)$ where $x$ is from $0$ to $1$. Noise is added to each curve, so $20$ curves are generated from each, resulting in a total of $40$ curves. I am trying to recover the original curves from those curves with noise. One way is to average over them with equal weight. However, some curves can be more noisy than others, so they should have lower weights. What method should I use?